# after reading the subject

Tags: email

I got a mail yesterday, I want to clarify few things w.r.t to email content & subject.

In response mail , I'm starting with

> I just want to clarify few things here, after reading the subject - *******

whether the usage of after reading the subject. is that correct usage?

Comment: "In regard to your mail, I would like to clarify a few things ..." could be an appropriate response.

Comment: Are you asking if this sentence is correct/acceptable: **I just want to clarify few things here, after reading the subject -**? If you are, then please edit your question to make this clearer and say why you think this construction might be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: "After reading the subject" is pretty much the only grammatical thing in this entire post. Making this just a proofreading request, and we don't do proofreading here.

Comment: I would like to know,which sentence we can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're saying and yes, you can say "after reading the subject". However, I would probably put it first, like "After reading the subject ____, I just want to clarify a few things here."

What you should say also depends on whether YOU are the one who wants to clarify something to them regarding the subject, or whether you are asking them to clarify something for you. I can't tell which it is from your example, so I can't really offer you a "better" sentence... which is fine, because your sentence DOES work and "after reading the subject" can be used how you have used it. 
Sometimes people prefer to say "After having read the subject..." or "Having read the subject..." or "Upon reading the subject...". Hope this helps.